# search option not working when condition apply in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
<?php
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ) {

  $id=$row["id"];
  $purchase_id=$row["purchase_id"];
  $sql1=mysql_query( "select *,DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y-%m-%d') as date from purchase_detail where id='$purchase_id'" );
  $row1=mysql_fetch_array( $sql1 );
  $date=$row1["date"];
  $material_detail=$row1["material"];
  $purchase_price=$row1["purchase_price"];
  $sales_price=$row1["sales_price"];
  $vendorname=$row1["vendorname"];
  $comname=$row1["comname"];
  $other_detail=$row1["other_detail"];
  $type=$row1["type"];

  echo"<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";

  $bill_no=$row["bill_no"];

  if ( $bill_no == '' ) {
    echo "<tr bgcolor='pink'>";
  }
  if ( $bill_no != '' ) // when i use if condition than search option not working
    {
    echo"<tr bgcolor='red'>";
  }
  else {
    echo"<tr bgcolor='white'>";
  }

  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='active' name='active[]' id='active' value='".$row["id"]."'></input></td>";
  echo "<td> ".$row["make_bill_id"]."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$row["bill_no"]."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$date."</td>";
  echo "<td> ".$material_detail."</td>";
  echo "<td> ".$other_detail."</td>";
  echo "<td> ".$purchase_price."</td>";
  echo "<td> ".$vendorname."</td>";
  echo "<td> ".$sales_price."</td>";
  echo "<td> ".$type."</td>";
  echo "<td> ".$comname."</td>";
  echo "<td> ".$row["assign_by"]."</td>";


  echo"</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: use if then elseif and then else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  // Remove this one
  //echo"<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";

  $bill_no=$row["bill_no"];

  if ( $bill_no == '' ) {
    echo "<tr bgcolor='pink'>";
  }
  else if ( $bill_no != '' ) // when i use if condition than search option not working
    {
    echo"<tr bgcolor='red'>";
  }
  else {
    echo"<tr bgcolor='white'>";
  }
```

Comment: $bill_no=$row["bill_no"];
     
if ($bill_no != '') 
{
echo"<tr bgcolor='red'>"; 
}

Comment: problem is when i use condition than search option not working  if i remove that condition than search tag working on screen????????

Comment: yes because you are adding <tr> tag two times. Use edited code. @Mukeshpatidar

Comment: if i remove echo"<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";  than condition not apply on row @ ruchish parikh

Comment: else condition apply bydefault on row when if not match. @Mukeshpatidar

Comment: for what? @Mukeshpatidar